# Documentation for Stack Overflow reputation graph (Flot)

Tags: javascript, flot, graphing, stackexchange-api

is there any documentation available to build Flot graph similar to what we can find in the Stack Overflow [profile/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341106?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) tab?

from the source code I can see that data is queried at this address: `/users/rep-graph/341106/" + ranges.xaxis.from.toFixed(1) + "/" + ranges.xaxis.to.toFixed(1)` but I don't know the values `from` and `to` fields **in the URL** can accept.

**EDIT**:

[image]

In this graph, we can see that two points are highlighted, and the result is that two *question* are listed on the side, which means that the plotted values are linked with *user-defined data*.

However, if I consider pkh's example, only the *points* (and a label) are provided to Flot:

```
label: "United States",
        data: [[1990, 18.9], [1991, 18.7] ....
```

So I'd like to see:

1. how to link data with points
2. how to update a panel according to graph selection [but maybe this part is not actually done by Flot itself]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, they are passing Javascript timestamps back via the URL.

So on the backend side, they must be doing something like this (pseudocode):

```
//get parameters from URL, non-rails people would just use POST or GET variables
$from = $_GET['from']
$to = $_GET['to']

//convert to timestamps in your language
$from = $from/1000
$to = $to/1000

//query your data source with these time-based restrictions
//return a JSON data set with the given restrictions, linking the known timestamps to labels
```

For your 2nd question, have your server-side return an associative array, linking the timestamp to a data object, which in this case contains Gain,Loss,Url,Title.  In the success callback, you display them.  Here's an example data object:

```
{ 1274774400000 : {
       Gain:0,
       Loss:10,
       Url:'http://asdf.com',
       Title:'We lost some rep here... boohoo'
    },
  1274947200000 : {
       Gain:10,
       Loss:0,
       Url:'http://asdf.com',
       Title:'We gained some rep here... woo!'
    }
}
```

You can see this type of object being used in the `showReputation` function in the page you referenced... except they returned a JSON array instead of an object.

Another feature you could easily add given the above data object:  a plotclick event that highlights the given data point when the click it.

Comment: thanks, so I can get a 'live' example with http://stackoverflow.com//users/rep-graph/341106/1273947200000/1274947200000 :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they're using flot's selection plugin.  Here's a [basic example of its use](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/selection.html).

`ranges` is a argument to the `plotselected` handler, and so `from` and `to` can be any valid value for the given axis. (Selection can be along x, y, or (x and y) axes.)

Comment: thanks; I actually already saw these examples, but unfortunately, none of them talk about data linked with values of the graph

Comment: In that case I don't understand the question. Can you clarify what you're finding unclear?